# trying to curl get image, but i get weird results

Tags: php, curl

this is my curl function:

```
function curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1;     SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'picturecookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
return $return;
}
```

an example image im trying to get:

http://static.fjcdn.com/large/pictures/39/29/3929d8_2637027.jpg

when i try getting the image with curl, i only get a file with random filesizes each time.
heres a list of bytes returned 6 times in a row;

```
12 654
12 627
12 632
12 632
12 583
12 627
```

the example image is 655kB

what am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I found why :>
The images are hotlink protected.
It was simply solved by changing the referer to the url the image was presented on.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting redirecteed to the funnyjunk index page without noticing ;-)